# Refresh Array after Insert

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have been getting great help on this site trying to create a clone process.  The user can clone up to 9 records.  I am almost there.  I am able to use a custom form and an apex class to insert the records that are created.  I  had to remove the caching from the apex class so I could do the insert.  The last step that I am struggling with is refreshing an array on the page when I insert the new records.  Initially, these records get loaded by using the wire service and an apex class to retrieve the records.  How do I refresh that process after the insert?  Here is my javascipt to save the array and also my apex.  Thank you!!`

```
saveClones() {
  console.log('$$$ here is the rowindex ' +  this.clonedGroupStructures);
  saveGroupStructures({ gs: this.clonedGroupStructures })
  .then(result => {
    this.message = result;
    this.error = undefined;
    if(this.message !== undefined) {
        this.clonedGroupStructures = []
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Account created',
                variant: 'success',
            }),
        );

      //update page
      this.bShowModal = false;
      this.isReadForm = false;
      this.isEditForm = false;
      this.isNewForm = false;
      this.isCloneForm = false;  
    }
 
})
.catch(error => {
    this.message = undefined;
    this.error = error;
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error creating record',
            message: error.body.message,
            variant: 'error',
        }),
    );
    console.log("error", JSON.stringify(this.error));
});
```

}

```
   @AuraEnabled ()
public static List<Group_Structure__c> saveGroupStructure (List<Group_Structure__c> gs) {
    try{
        insert gs;
        return gs;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        system.debug('Im in apex error');
        throw new AuraHandledException('The records did not save: '
                                        + ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have 2 options that I can think of:

1. If you're using wire, you can just use `refreshApex` and it'll display new data from the server.

```
refreshApex(/*your wire property/response*/)
//update page
      this.bShowModal = false;
      this.isReadForm = false;
      this.isEditForm = false;
      this.isNewForm = false;
      this.isCloneForm = false;
```

2. If you want to set your response from Apex to be displayed then you need to reassign the array variable

```
this.myArray = response;
// or

this.myArray = [...response]; // if need to do modification to items on UI.
```